# Are there any possibilities for Neat Download Manager integration to safari?

Tags: safari, monterey, safari-extensions, apple-silicon

I've tried with Chrome and it works great, but for some reasons i have to stick with safari browser, can I tweak it to integrate with Neat Download Manager either as extension or just tweak/play around? Thank you. My device is MBA M1 with Monterey 12.5.1.

Comment: Web page says 'has browser extension'...

Comment: Ah i found it, sorry